# Dee Jay taunt to Sagat SFIV

Tags: ios, street-fighter-iv

Just playing Street Fighter IV on the iPhone and lost to Dee Jay using Sagat and received the following taunt:

"They say you are the king of tigers. Now I know why."

I don't understand how this is supposed to be an insult, 'king of the tigers' sounds like a cool thing to be called, but why would it be appropriate if I just lost?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not meant as an insult, but as a sign of respect.